# iterate through SimpleXMLElement Object in php

Tags: php, simplexml

I can't iterate through this xml file. I'm using `simplexml_load_file()`. does anyone have a solution? Thanks for your time. I'm a newbie!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[ReferenceMember] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Agency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ID] => xx
                [ActivityID] => xxxxx
                [ActivityReferenceID] => xxxxx
            )

    )

[Member] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Agency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ID] => xx
                [ActivityID] => xxxx
                [ActivityReferenceID] => xxxx
            )

    )

[SubmissionID] => xxxx
[Company] => xxxxx

[Emails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Email1] => xxxx@xxx.com
    )

[UploadedDate] => 24/11/14
)
```

this is what I've tried

```
$data = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($data as $item) {

        foreach ($item->item as $entry) {
            $this->set_date($entry->UploadedDate);

        }

}

$array = array(
            "DATE" => $this->get_date()

        );

var_dump($array);
```

this is what i get

```
array(1) {
  ["DATE"]=>
  NULL
}
```

when i try to acces object value

```
var_dump($date->UploadedDate);

object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "24/11/14"
}
```

Comment: It's easier to reproduce examples if you provide the actual XML used, rather than a dump of the SimpleXML object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you've given us, you don't need to loop at all, because you only want one answer, and you know exactly where to find it:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file($file);
$this->set_date( (string)$data->UploadedDate );
```

Note that I've used `(string)` here; this removes the SimpleXML magic from the found value, which will probably be what you want later. `echo` does this for you, so `echo $data->UploadedDate;` would show what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. it works like this. however when i trye to change date format `$this->date = date("Y-m-d", $date);` i get this date : "1970-01-01". let me know if you have an idea on this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: @S.B `date()` expects a timestamp - an integer representing the number of seconds since 1970 - not a preformatted string. The easiest way to convert from one format to another is using `$timestamp = strtotime($formatted_date); echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);` or `$dateObject = new DateTime($formatted_date); echo $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');` (None of which has anything to do with this question, so if you're still stuck, search for or ask a new question.)